# Leaflet maxBounds - bounds do not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I tried out Leafletjs maxBounds with [example code I found at Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/maxbounds/).

Below you find my complete code, also in a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wolfmuc/1zyL4q4a/6/).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>map - leaflet test bounds</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <!-- leafletjs -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            html, body, #map {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map">
        <script>

            var southWest = L.latLng(40.712, -74.227),
                northEast = L.latLng(40.774, -74.125),
                mybounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

            var map = L.map('map').setView([40.743, -74.176], 17);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' , {
                maxBounds: mybounds,
                maxZoom: 18,
                minZoom: 16,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }) .addTo(map);

            L.marker([40.743, -74.176]) .addTo(map);

        </script>
    </div>        
</body>
```

The jsfiddle result looks odd, I don't know why.

Why doesn't the upper code work like the Mapbox example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use bounds as an option of L.tileLayer, and not maxBounds.

[Bounds reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-bounds)

Also, it seems you've loaded a wrong file for the leaflet.css in JSFiddle, the correct source is this: http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css

Finally, avoid to use percent sizes in JSFiddle, use pixel ones instead.
Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1zyL4q4a/4/

```
 L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' , {
            bounds: mybounds,
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 16,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I think maxBounds is right. "When this option is set, the map restricts the view to the given geographical bounds, bouncing the user back when he tries to pan outside the view." [link](leafletjs.com/reference.html)[/link] I want the user bounced back. I checked the css in jsfidlle. It was wrong. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: maxBounds is for restricting the mapview (use with map, not with L.tileLayer), bounds is for restricting tiles loading

Comment: maxBounds and bounds is very similiar from my point of view. I´ll try it.

Comment: Strage, your jsfiddle works fine for me. The map view it's bouncing back when I reach the given bounds.

Comment: It works. Yesterday I didnt´t reach the given bounds. I was too tired to notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This is the (my) final code.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 16,
    maxBounds: [
        //south west
        [40.712, -74.227],
        //north east
        [40.774, -74.125]
        ], 
}).setView([40.743, -74.176], 17);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}) .addTo(map);

L.marker([40.743, -74.176]) .addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless im mistaken your example you have followed in the first example is not a leaflet map the api provider is mapbox. The giveaway is in the top html script links of your first example you followed. Another is the unusual behaviour of my leaflet map when using the code from first example.

The correct provider of answer uses the leaflet API as seen in

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' , {
bounds: mybounds,
maxZoom: 18,
minZoom: 16,
attribution: '© [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org) contributors'
}).addTo(map);